# Should I test this code? (immediate method call assignment to class member)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, testing, jestjs

```
class MyClassComponent {
  hasAccess = this.hasAccessToSomething();

  constructor(private numberService: NumberService) {}

  private hasAccessToSomething(): boolean {
    return this.numberService.getNumber() > 5;
  }
}
```

Should I test wheter `hasAccess` equals to `false` or `true` dependently on the `numberService.getNumber()` value? This is an initial class state where I called a private method, a method that isn't supposed to be tested, and assigned its value to my public class member.

If the answer is yes - how to do that using jasmine/jest with TestBed?

```
let component: MyClassComponent;

beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [
      MyClassComponent,
      NumberService
    ]
  });

  component = TestBed.inject(MyClassComponent);
});
```

I could mock `NumberService.getNumber` method but the problem is that after the mock is created, I can't reinitialize `hasAccess` assignment. I could call `this.hasAccessToSomething` in e.g. `ngOnInit` and then test `hasAccess` value calling again `ngOnInit` but I wouldn't like to complicate class for tests purpose. With such easy class I could get rid of `TestBed` and reinitialize component using `new MyClassComponent` but let's imagine that this class is much bigger with much more dependencies.

How would you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that's what you looking for

```
let component: MyClassComponent;

beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [MyClassComponent, NumberService],
  });
});

describe("with default NumberService result", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    component = TestBed.inject(MyClassComponent);
  });

    it('should ....',()=>{...})
});

describe("with mocked NumberService result", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.overrideProvider(NumberService, {
      useValue: { getNumber: () => 999 },
    });
    component = TestBed.inject(MyClassComponent);
  });

    it('should ....',()=>{...})
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jasmine.Spy` for such purpose and turn `hasAccess` into a getter property:

```
export class MyClassComponent {
  public get hasAccess(): boolean {
    return this.hasAccessToSomething()
  }
  ...
```

Inside your tests:

```
describe('MyClassComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [
      MyClassComponent,
      NumberService
    ]
  });
    ...
  })

  it('should have access if numberService.getNumber() returns more than 5', () => {
    spyOn(TestBed.inject(NumberService), 'getNumber').and.returnValue(6)
    expect(component.hasAccess).toBeTrue()
  })


  it('should not have access if numberService.getNumber() returns less than 5', () => {
    spyOn(TestBed.inject(NumberService), 'getNumber').and.returnValue(4)
    expect(component.hasAccess).toBeFalse()
  })

})
```

*if you DO NOT want* to turn `hasAccess` into a `getter` property then you should scope the creation of the component right before mocking/spying on the service by using nested describe blocks:

```
describe('MyComponent...', () => {

  beforeEach(() =>  /*build the module*/)

  describe('when NumberService.getNumber returns more than 5', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      spyOn(TestBed.inject(NumberService), 'getNumber').and.returnValue(6)
      component = ...
    })

    it('should have access', () => expect(component.hasAccess).toBeTrue())
  })
  // Symmetric for less than 5
```

Comment: I didn't think about creating hasAccess as getter which results in what I wanted to achieve so I'm gonna give you a point. I'm wondering what if I'd like to use this getter inside angular template html file. How it would impact change detection. It is a method after all and as far as I know calling method to display something can trigger a lot of change detections.

Comment: You may also update the change detection strategy to "OnPush" inside your `@Component({...})` annotation but then you're required to use more RxJS-ish code. Otherwise you might keep it a regular property and mock the service before creating the component

Comment: Well, that's a lot of to maintain just to have the immediate assignment. Looks like there is no way to eat a cookie and have a cookie. I have a method which value depends on outer context and even if it's private, the hasAccess class member takes a role of public API which should be tested in that case. Getter will affect change detection, onpush will force me to take care of the component manual change detecting in required places and reinitializing component in test file will result in much more code there. I'll move the initialization to ngOnInit. You gave me the answer, thumb up :)

Comment: You could also just make the method public or do dirty castings to get a hold of it. After all that's what you're interested into testing since it contains your "business logic" the property itself just caches and holds a value.